# from ccxt how can I get amount of coins I have?

Tags: python, binance, ccxt

```
import ccxt

binance = ccxt.binance(config={
    'apiKey': '...',
    'secret': '...',
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',
    }
})

print(binance.fetch_balance()['info']['positions'])
```

From this code, I want to get the amount of coin I have. not the wallet balance.

response:

```
{'symbol': 'ZILUSDT', 'initialMargin': '418.22854400', 'maintMargin': '41.82285440', 'unrealizedProfit': '87.68853824', 'positionInitialMargin': '418.22854400', 'openOrderInitialMargin': '0', 'leverage': '10', 'isolated': False, 'entryPrice': '0.0612375840409', 'maxNotional': '100000', 'positionSide': 'BOTH', 'positionAmt': '-69728', 'notional': '-4182.28544000', 'isolatedWallet': '0', 'updateTime': '1642505268697', 'bidNotional': '0', 'askNotional': '0'}
```

it doesn't shows me the amount. how can I?
( I want to close the total coin I have  so I have to know the amount of it )

Comment: Go onto binance and delete that apiKey and secret

Answer (score 2):

```
import ccxt
import sys

print('python', sys.version)
print('CCXT Version:', ccxt.__version__)

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': '...',
    'secret': '...',
})
# exchange.verbose = True

print(len([coin for coin, balance in exchange.fetch_balance()
       ['total'].items() if balance > 0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

'positionAmt': '-69728', 'notional': '-4182.28544000',

it shows that you have 68728 ZIL on short position.
the total value of this balance in usdt is 4182.285 USDT.